# CakePHPでhasManyを使った更新が上手くいかない

Tags: cakephp

cakePHP 2.4.9を使用しています。
以下2つのテーブルをhasManyモデルを使用して結合し、追加、編集、更新を想定。

eventsテーブル

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adult_price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adult_age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `access` text,
  `description` text,
  `minimun_participants_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_policy_flag` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meals_flug` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_of_day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pickup_flag` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration_hour` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pv` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

events_schedulesテーブル

```
CREATE TABLE `events_schedules` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `start_hour` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_min` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_hour` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_min` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Model/Event.php

```
<?php 
class EventController extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Event' => array(
            'className' => 'Event',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => '',
        ),
    );
}
```

となっており、一つのイベントIDにつき複数のスケジュールを追加できるようにしています。
コントローラー側の処理です。
Controller/EventController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');

class EventsController extends AppController
{

    public $uses = array('Event', 'EventSchedule');

    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        if ($this->request->is('Event') || $this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($id == null) {
                $id = $this->Event->getLastInsertID();
            } else {
                $this->EventSchedule->deleteAll(array('EventSchedule.event_id' => $id));
            }
            $this->Event->id = $id;

            if ($this->Event->save($this->request->data)) {
                if ($this->request->data('EventsSchedule')) {
                    $this->EventsSchedule->saveAll($this->request->data['EventsSchedule'], array('deep' => true));
                }
                {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('登録が完了しました'));
                }

                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', $this->Event->id));
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('失敗しました'));
            }
        }

        $options = array('conditions' => array('Event.id' => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Event->find('first', $options);
        $this->set('event', $this->request->data);
    }
```

View側では複数のインプットを保存できるように用意
View/Events/edit.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Event', array('type' => 'button', 'action' => 'edit','div' => false)); ?>
    （中略）
    .
    .
    .
    <?php 
    $count = 0; 
    foreach($this->data['EventsSchedule'] as $Eventschedule): ?> 
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="8">スケジュール</th>
            <td>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="ui two fields">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>日本語</label>
                            <?php echo $this->Form->input('EventsSchedule.'. $count . '.title', array('type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => 'スケジュールタイトル(日本語)', 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => false)) ;?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>詳細</label>
                            <?php echo $this->Form->input('EventsSchedule.'. $count . '.description', array('type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => 'スケジュール詳細(日本語)', 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => false)) ;?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="ui fields">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>開始時間</label>
                            <?php echo $this->Form->input('EventsSchedule.'.$count. '.start_hour',array('type' => 'select','options' => Configure::read('Hour.codes'),'class' => 'select', 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => false)); ?>：
                            <?php echo $this->Form->input('EventsSchedule.'.$count. '.start_min', array('type' => 'select','options' => Configure::read('Minute.codes'),'class' => 'select', 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => false)); ?> 〜 
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>終了時間</label> 
                            <?php echo $this->Form->input('EventsSchedule.'.$count. '.end_hour',array('type' => 'select','options' => Configure::read('Hour.codes'),'class' => 'select', 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => false)); ?>：
                            <?php echo $this->Form->input('EventsSchedule.'.$count. '.end_min', array('type' => 'select','options' => Configure::read('Minute.codes'),'class' => 'select', 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => false)); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => '登録・編集', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
```

ここまではなんとかで用意でき、以下のことが実現できません。
・更新を押した際にEvents_scheduleテーブルにevent_idが保存されない
・スケジュールの入力欄を動的に追加できるようにしたい

どなたかご教示いただけると幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `Events_calendar`というテーブルは`events`や`events_schedules`のテーブルと異なるテーブルですか。

Comment: view側, edit.ctp は`$this->Form->create(...)`, `$this->Form->end()` の部分も含めて記載してください。

Comment: コントローラーのクラス名`Event`となっていますが、モデルクラスとかぶるのでこれではエラーが出て動作しないと思いますが`EventsController`の間違いではないですか?

Comment: @summea さま、すみません、こちらEvents_calendarではなく、Events_scheduleの間違いでした。修正しております。

Comment: @nojimage さま、上記2点修正いたしました。宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

いろいろと例示コード上におかしな点がありますが、保存部分だけに絞って回答します。

`EventsController::edit()`において`$this->Event->save()`の後に`$this->EventSchedule->saveAll()`を実行していますが、これはまとめて`saveAssociated`を使いましょう。

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

```
if ($this->Event->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
    // 保存成功時の処理
} else {
    // 保存失敗時の処理
}
```

また、View側でEvendScheduleのidが指定されていないため、このままではEventScheduleレコードが毎回新規作成されてしまいます。

そこで、View側で

```
<?php
foreach($this->request->data['EventsSchedule'] as $count => $Eventschedule): ?> 
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="8">スケジュール</th>
        <td>
          <?php echo $this->Form->hidden("EventsSchedule.$count.id"); ?>
```

のようにして、EventsSchedule.idをhiddenでセットしておきます。

（foreachループで$countをインクリメントしていますが、このようにforeachでキーとして取得すればインクリメントは不要ですよね。）